# How do i make a socket in python to be able to receive but also to send in a while true loop?

Tags: python, sockets, client

So, if i want to make a "chat" with python sockets, i need to be able to write a message and send it anytime i want, maybe by doing something like this:

```
   while True:
       msg = input()
       socket.send(msg)
```

But, if i do that, i will not be able to use socket.recv() without making python wait for a message and stop the program until it gets received, i tried to solve this with threading but it of course can't work like that. How can i solve this?

Below the attempt by threading.

```py
def receive():
     while True:
         client.recv(2048)
looprecv = threading.Thread(target=receive())
looprecv.start()
while True:
     message = input("messaggio: ")
     send(message)
     if message == "!exit":
         break
```

Comment: Of course it can work with threading.  What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: because when i tried it still blocked the program, i think that's because even if thread it, python tries to execute a single line per time, so the script still gets blocked.

Comment: Show some code.  You certainly can have a thread reading a socket and a thread writing a socket.

Comment: ```def receive():
    while True:
        client.recv(2048)


looprecv = threading.Thread(target=receive())

looprecv.start()

while True:
    message = input("messaggio: ")
    send(message)
    if message == "!exit":
        break
```

Comment: Please edit the question.  Comment code is unreadable.  Make sure it is a *complete* example. See [mcve].  You didn't start the thread correctly.  `target=receive` not `target=receive()`.  The latter calls the function in the main thread, and the *return value* is passed as the target function, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, you was right. i fixed that. Thanks a lot.